# ImageMagick module Issue

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I have seen that this already exists in Stackoverflow but any of them happen what it's happening to me...

I have Laravel 5.8, PHP 7.2.24.

I am using the library Intervention which it modifies the images, etc. The issue is that it requires a PHP library that it is ImageMagick.

I installed it with this:

```
sudo apt-get install php-imagick
```

I checked the php.ini and it says this:

```
imagick

imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.4.3RC2
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114
```

How you see it is enabled, BUT when I will use the library Intervention, it says one more time:

```
message: "ImageMagick module not available with this PHP installation."
```

I already restarted the server so It's not that... so I wonder what could the problem be? because it's enabled, it's working but it still does not work...

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?